# How to tell what apps are not being used?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

I have a iPad 4th gen. I want to delete unused apps.  Is there a way to easily tell what apps are not being used?

Comment: I think that feature was introduced in iOS 11.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 11, you can set up your ipad to move unused apps. Go to Settings and then tap General. In General there is a page for iPhone Storage. Here there is an option to remove unused apps. If you enable this then unused apps will be removed.

Someone reported on this site that they had a problem with there iPad not accurately determining the last used date. That person was getting this "app never used" setting for all apps. I assume you want to avoid that.

If you scroll down on same page where you enable the removal of unused apps, there is a list of all apps on your device. Under the name of each app is the last used date. Make sure that that field does not have "Never Used" for apps you know you have used.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect use case for the Offload Unused Apps feature introduced in iOS 11.

This feature is designed to automatically remove apps you're not using. It's a low risk approach because even though the apps are removed, any documents and data are still kept in case you want to re-install the apps later (assuming they're still available/compatible).

Unfortunately, your iPad is not compatible with iOS 11.

For users with compatible devices, to enable this feature (assuming your on iOS 11), go to **Settings > iPad Storage** and then tap on *Enable* to activate the **Offload Unused Apps** option.

**NOTE:** - While in the Settings > General > iPad Storage screen your list of Apps will populate to indicate how much storage space they’re taking and also when they were last used (or if never used).